# jQuery Matrix Values from CSS

Tags: jquery, matrix, css-transforms

I'm trying to get Matrix values from CSS transform properties, but for some reason it's not working.

```
var object = $(this);

var transMatrix = object.css("-webkit-transform") || 
                  object.css("-moz-transform") || 
                  object.css("-ms-transform") || 
                  object.css("-o-transform") || 
                  object.css("transform");

console.log("Matrix = " + transMatrix);

var values = transMatrix.split('(')[1];
    values = transMatrix.split(')')[0];
    values = transMatrix.split(',');

console.log("Values = " + values);

var a = values[0];
console.log("a = " + a);
var b = values[1];
console.log("b = " + b);

var scale = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
console.log("Scale = " + scale);                                        

var sin = b/scale;
console.log("Sin = " + sin);

var transScale = Math.round(scale * 100) / 100;
console.log("Transform Scale = " + transScale);

var transAngle = Math.round(Math.asin(sin) * (180/Math.PI));
console.log("Transform Angle = " + transAngle);
```

But when I output this, console shows:

```
Matrix = matrix(0.496273075820661, 0.06093467170257374, -0.06093467170257374, 0.496273075820661, 0, 0)
Values = matrix(0.496273075820661, 0.06093467170257374, -0.06093467170257374, 0.496273075820661, 0, 0)
a = matrix(0.496273075820661
b =  0.06093467170257374
Scale = NaN
Sin = NaN
Transform Scale = NaN
Transform Angle = NaN
```

It seems to be returning `'undefined'` after it's got the Matrix values from the CSS (Which is working correctly)

Is there something wrong with my 'split' method?

Comment: `console.log("a = " + sin)` should be `console.log("a = " + a)` -- throughout your code you're logging the wrong variables.

Comment: @Blazemonger Long day! But just changed them and updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var values = transMatrix.split('(')[1];
values = transMatrix.split(')')[0];
values = transMatrix.split(',');
```

should be

```
var values = transMatrix.split('(')[1];
values = values.split(')')[0];
values = values.split(',');
```

or simply chain them:

```
var values = transMatrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
```

In fact, you can do this a little more cleanly using regular expressions and [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
var values = transMatrix.match(/[\d\.]+/g);
```

Comment: Magic! The chain one is the best in my opinion. Regex just messes with my head... Haha. The weird thing about this was, it worked previously with the code in my question, but then broke...

Comment: Your regex won't work when transMatrix is a 3d transform, because it will also match the 3 in matrix3d. You could solve this with this regex: transMatrix.match(/[\d\.]+(?=[,\)])/g)
This checks if the number is followed by a comma or closing bracket